# Bonnet MVT proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm looking for a proof of the Bonnet MVT that avoids the use of Riemann-Stieltjes integral and is shorter than the classical proof using the Riemann integral definition and Abel's lemma.  For anyone who doesn't know the statement, it's:

Assume $g$ is non-decreasing and non-negative on $[a, b]$ and that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ (I myself am only interested in $f$ continuous).    Then there exists $c \in (a, b)$ where \begin{equation*} \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \, dx = g(b) \int_c^b f(x) \, dx. \end{equation*}